# MySQL Workbench's treatment of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How do I force MySQL Workbench, when using a foreign key, to perform an INSERT to my referenced table before the INSERT to the referencing table. Without the obvious solution of editing the generated SQL by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William,

Unfortunately, MySQL workbench doesn't work this way. You'd have to write the SQL yourself to do this. If you need this often, you might think about writing a stored procedure that handles this for you.